How to build .wasm for tree-sitter-latex or (emcc command failed)?
I want to make server side syntax highlighter for latex with web-tree-sitter. But I cannot make a .wasm file for tree-sitter-latex.
I made a issue in github repo. But could someone build me .wasm file for tree-sitter-latex please.
